# How can i force laravel to do batch(multiple) insert in sync() method?

Tags: php, laravel

When i use `sync()` method laravel do a lot of separate insert queries in  my intermediate table like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tag_user` (`user_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES ('59', '60')
INSERT INTO `tag_user` (`user_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES ('59', '61')
```

I want it to do one multiple insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tag_user` (`user_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES ('59', '60'), ('59', '61')
```

Is it possible? I'm using MySql. It would be nice to have `attach()` method that will accept array as `detach()` method do. Did someone do this?

Comment: Are you sure? It does that by default, [right here.](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/database/query/grammars/grammar.php#L400). Everything is transformed into batch mode as you want it.

Comment: Look [here](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Laravel.Database.Eloquent.Relationships.Has_Many_And_Belongs_To.html#118). As you can see it does single insert by means of `attach()` method through foreach loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how i solved it:

### My models

In my application each user has many tags(many to many realationship). It's called [toxi](http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html) database schema.
My user table is called 'users', tags table is called 'tags'. And intermediate table is called 'tag_user' that has 'tag_id' and 'user_id' columns.

User model:

```
class User extends \Eloquent 
{
    public static $timestamps = false;

    public function tags()
    {
          return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Models\Tag');
    }
}
```

Tag model:

```
class Tag extends \Eloquent 
{
    public static $timestamps = false;
}
```

### How i replaced `sync()` method

This is how i forced laravel to do `sync()` method using multiple insert:

```
//$currentUser is a model loaded from database
//Like this: $currentUser = Auth::user();

$newLinks = array();
$idsToSync = array();

foreach ($tags as $tag)
{
    array_push($idsToSync, $tag->id);
}

//$currentUser->tags()->sync($idsToSync);

$currentIds = $currentUser->tags()->pivot()->lists('tag_id');

$idsToAttach = array_diff($idsToSync, $currentIds);

foreach ($idsToAttach as $value)
{
    $newLink = array(
                    'user_id' => $currentUser->id,
                    'tag_id' => $value
                     );

    $newLinks[] = $newLink;
}        

if (count($newLinks) > 0)
{
    \DB::table('tag_user')->insert($newLinks);
}

$idsToDetach = array_diff($currentIds, $idsToSync);

if (count($idsToDetach) > 0)
{
    $currentUser->tags()->detach($idsToDetach);
}
```

This code does one multiple insert instead of many single ones.

Answer (score 1):

Ya, i was working on the same thing few days back,

eloquent does multiple insert in one sql.

but make sure all loops are equal columns and fields, i was trying to remove the one that does not have value the first time, and mysql wont work...

eg:

```
array(
    array('name' => 'blah'),
    array('name' => 'blah')
)
User::insert($data)
```

but if you want to update existing records than you need to do raw query.

eg:

```
$keyString = '("';
$valString = '("';
foreach ($blah as $k => $v) {
     $keyString .= $k . '", '
}
```

the goal is to return something like this

```
$keyString // (name, email, bla, bla)
$valString // ('john doe', 'email@email.com', 'bla', 'bla'), ('someone', 'email@email.com', 'bla', 'bla'),
```

than

```
DB::query( 'replace into users' . $keyString . ' values ' . $valString );
```

make sure you use array count to do a check whether is the last array for comma or not

eg:

```
(++counter === count ? '),' : ')' ;
```

this need to refactored

Comment: Thanks for answer man.) But i've got slightly different problem.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to use Laravel's `DB::transaction()` and put the sync in it as a closure.